# How to use http-proxy-middleware with react and passport.js

Tags: reactjs, express, passport.js, http-proxy-middleware

Well,I am working on a react app.I have an express server at localhost:5000 and the react app on localhost:3000.I am going through the google oauth flow using passportjs.Now the real problem is I have used the http-proxy-middleware to go to localhost:5000/auth/google from my react app using the log in button which directs to /auth/google.Then after authenticating I should be returned to the callbackURL which is /auth/google/callback.then from here i should be redirected to localhost:3000/surveys but I am getting redirected to localhost:5000/surveys which does not exist.So i am getting error:can not get /surveys.But when i log out using the logout button which directs to /api/logout then i am getting redirected to the homepage at '/' which is at localhost:3000.So why am i getting redirected to localhost:3000/ and not localhost:5000/ in this case.And how can i go to localhost:3000/surveys instead of localhost:5000/surveys as mentioned in the beginning?

```js
//passport js file
const passport = require("passport");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const keys = require("../config/keys");

const User = mongoose.model("users");
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then((user) => {
    done(null, user);
  });
});
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: keys.googleClientID,
      clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
      callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
      proxy: true,
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      const existingUser = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });
      if (existingUser) {
        return done(null, existingUser);
      }
      const user = await new User({ googleId: profile.id }).save();
      done(null, user);
    }
  )
);
//the routes for my express server
const passport = require("passport");

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.get(
    "/auth/google",
    passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile", "email"] })
  );
  app.get(
    "/auth/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google"),
    (req, res) => {
      res.redirect("/surveys");
    }
  );
  app.get("/api/current", (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.user);
  });
  app.get("/api/logout", (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect("/");
  });
};
//the proxy setup in react src folder
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    "/auth/google",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "http://localhost:5000",
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
  app.use(
    "/api",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "http://localhost:5000",
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
//my react header component
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
class Header extends React.Component {
  renderContent() {
    switch (this.props.auth) {
      case null:
        return;
      case false:
        return (
          <li>
            <a href="/auth/google">Log In</a>
          </li>
        );
      default:
        return (
          <li>
            <a href="/api/logout">Log Out</a>
          </li>
        );
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <nav>
        <div className="nav-wrapper">
          <Link to={this.props.auth ? "/surveys" : "/"} className="brand-logo">
            Emaily
          </Link>
          <ul className="right">{this.renderContent()}</ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { auth: state.auth };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well,just removing the change origin from proxy did the work!